# Array with a single value cause error when used in Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am building a RandomForest Model

It works fine in some cases and crashes in others.

```
>>> type(z)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> z
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

I build the label list through this line of code

```
y = z[:, i]
```

`i` is an array that can have 1 or more values

```
i = [14,83,33]

or 

i = [26]
```

Here is my code

```
i=[4,15,33]
y = z[:, i]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=TestSize, random_state=42)
mdl= RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, n_jobs=-1)
mdl.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_hat = mdl.predict(X_test)
```

Here are the cases that I have

**CASE 1**

```
>>> i=[4,15,33]
>>> z[:, i]
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

works fine

**CASE 2**
here I replaced `i` with hardcoding inside `z`

```
>>> z[:, (4,15,33)]
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

**CASE 3**
`i` is a single value

```
>>> i=[26]
>>> z[:, i]
array([[1],
       [0],
       [1],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       ...
       [1],
       [0],
       [0]], dtype=uint8)
```

and this is causing an error when running in RandomForest algorithm

```
>>> mdl.fit(X_train, y_train)
<stdin>:1: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples,), for example using ravel().
RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, n_jobs=-1)
```

**CASE 4**
when I hardcode case 3

```
>>> z[:, (26)]
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

and RandomForest works fine.

My question,

Why doesn't CASE 3 work and how do I get it working without hardcoding?

Comment: "X" and "y" values are unclear to me. Please add extra details regarding your input data. Also, have a look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using scikit-learn, when the target has a single column you should pass a 1d array instead of a column vector (nx1 array) as stated in [this link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/80598905e517759b4696c74ecc35c6e2eb508cff/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L343).

You can change it as `z[:,i[0] if len(i)==1 else i]`!